# How do I denote a specific rovibrational transition?

Tags: notation, ir-spectroscopy

I am using a linelist from HITRAN, which gives me a whole lot of extra data and I want to denote the transitions accurately. But I don't know what to use for rovibrational transitions. The following parameters are given (separated by semicolons):

E'; u(E'); E"; u(E"); v1'; v2'; v3'; J'; Ka'; Kc'; s'; v1"; v2"; v3"; J"; Ka"; Kc"; s"; t'; t".

Now, using these, how do I denote a specific rovibrational transition?

Comment: Just to make it clearer, you should use the maths mode for the symbols (‘v’ is not a symbol that gets used, but ‘$\nu$’ and ‘$\upsilon$’ *are*).

Comment: Sorry for that, but this is how the .txt file shows all transitions. So I stuck to their method for this. I just need to know which notation I have to use for such a transition.

Comment: Oh... that's inconvenient... I'll take a look and see what I can do. What type of molecules are you looking at? (I think the symbols depend on the type of rotor it is, to a certain extent)

Comment: Very sorry for this late response, I didn't get notified. But the molecule in question is H2O! And if you can, do you have any links/references to further explanations on the notations?